# The most durable Wi-Fi router under 200$

Tags: wifi, router, durability

I am looking for a Wi-Fi router, in the 100-200 $ price range, with the following characteristics:

- all ports are — Gigabit Ethernet
- guest Wi-Fi network option (in addition to home Wi-Fi network)
- it is really important that the router would work stably, without reboots
- I am looking for most durable (i.e. work without repair and/or maintenance) option, in said price range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the question would get more attention and answer(s), if it was posted on [networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

---

Primary options, I came up with:

1. [MikroTik hAP ac²](https://mikrotik.com/product/hap_ac2)

   - pros:

     - possibilities of what can be achieved with proper setup are, virtually, limitless (though, there is a downside — see cons)
     - 4 ethernet ports (+ 1 "WAN")
   - cons:

     - difficulty of setting up: all the options you would want for a home use (like setting password for the Wi-Fi and setting up guest Wi-Fi network) are not obvious to do and **require reading** of manuals or [MikroTik wiki](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Main_Page).
2. [Xiaomi Mi WiFi Router 3G](https://www.router-reset.com/reset-manuals/Xiaomi/MiWiFi-3G)

   - pros:

     - **PRICE** (you could get it from China for ~35-40$)
     - custom firmware (with English interface) is available
   - cons:

     - only 2 ethernet ports (+ 1 "WAN")
     - stock firmware is in chinese
     - flash of custom firmware is tricky

Other options to consider:

3. [SNR-CPE-ME1](https://www.router-reset.com/reset-manuals/NAG/SNR-CPE-ME1)
4. [ASUS RT-AC68U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC68U/)